# Python equivalent for typedef

Tags: python, user-defined-types

What is the python way to define a (non-class) type like:

```
typedef Dict[Union[int, str], Set[str]] RecordType
```

Comment: In what context - do you want to define a new type that you can then use for type hints?

Comment: [GenericAlias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This would simply do it?

```
from typing import Dict, Union, Set

RecordType = Dict[Union[int, str], Set[str]]


def my_func(rec: RecordType):
    pass


my_func({1: {'2'}})
my_func({1: {2}})
```

This code will generate a warning from your IDE on the second call to `my_func`, but not on the first. As @sahasrara62 indicated, more here https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias

Since **Python 3.9**, the preferred syntax would be:

```
from typing import Union

RecordType = dict[Union[int, str], set[str]]
```

The built-in types can be used directly for type hints and the added imports are no longer required.

Since **Python 3.10**, the preferred syntax is

```
RecordType = dict[int | str, set[str]]
```

The `|` operator is a simpler way to create a union of types, and the import of `Union` is no longer required.

Since **Python 3.12**, the preferred syntax is

```
type RecordType = dict[int | str, set[str]]
```

The `type` keyword explicitly indicates that this is a type alias.

Comment: I love how elegant and easy to understand Python's syntax is

Answer (score 9):

In case users look for a *distinct* nominal typedef:

```
from typing import Dict, Union, Set, NewType

RecordType = Dict[Union[int, str], Set[str]]
DistinctRecordType = NewType("DistinctRecordType", Dict[Union[int, str], Set[str]])

def foo(rec: RecordType):
    pass

def bar(rec: DistinctRecordType):
    pass

foo({1: {"2"}})
bar(DistinctRecordType({1: {"2"}}))
bar({1: {"2"}}) # <--- this will cause a type error
```

This snippet demonstrates that only explicit casting will do.

```
$ mypy main.py
main.py:14: error: Argument 1 to "bar" has incompatible type "Dict[int, Set[str]]"; expected "DistinctRecordType"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```